# $.trim().val is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3, jquery-1.7, jquery-migrate

I am working on updating jQuery version of our applications from jquery version 1.7 to 3.6 so, I am facing issue with 'trim' method. we have used trim method like in old jQuery version but it has changed in latest jQuery 3.6 so, I have modified it using accordingly to 3.6 but still it is showing error as **'$.trim(...).val is not a function'**

my old jQuery script(1.7):

```
var my_variable1 = $("#my_variable1_id").val().trim();
```

my new jQuery trim method is (3.6):

```
var my_variable1 = $("#my_variable1_id").val() === null ? '' : $.trim("#my_variable1_id").val();
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: JS string object has a native `trim` method as a prototype so that you can use that no matter `jQuery` version has it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no reason to use `$.trim`. As [the docs put it](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

> Note: This API has been deprecated in jQuery 3.5; please use the native String.prototype.trim method instead.

Take the value, alternate it with the empty string, and trim - not with jQuery, but with plain JavaScript (which was introduced around a decade ago and should be usable everywhere).

```
var my_variable1 = ($("#my_variable1_id").val() || '').trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope you will solve this problem just modifying something like this**

```
var str = $.trim($("#my_variable1_id").val());
```